# How do I change the onPause method of an APK file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onpause

I have an APK file that it requires on Internet connection. But when I click the Home button it loses its connection and can't use the Internet in onPause mode. How can I change the onPause method to do what I want in my application without losing the connection?

For example, I want it to click somewhere to unlock something in a specific time in my app. But at that time I'm sleeping and I can't do that. I just can put my app in onPause mode when I'm sleeping and make a schedule to do my favor.

Answer (score 0):

You better should use **Service** class for your task. Then kill it calling

```
stopSevice(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
```

It won't stop unless Android system kill it or You kill it.

For example:
Suppose, you want to download a picture from internet with a button click. Now to download a picture you code a service class.

**DownLoadPicture.class**

```
public class DownLoadPicture extends Service

    @Override
    private void onCreate(){
    //Download your picture now here

    }
```

And when your picture is downloaded then just kill your service calling

```
stopSelf();
```

Or, you can kill the service from your MainActivity. To kill the service from your MainActivity call

```
stopService(getApplicationContext(), DownLoadPicture.class);
```

So, now as you are saying that when your app goes on onPause then you lost internet connection. For solving this:-
Put all your codr in the DownLoadPicture class's **onCreate** method that you put in your MainActivity to do your internet task. And I hope you won't lost your internet connection then.

And then on your MainActivity's onCreate method put:-

```
startService(getApplicationContext, DownLoadPicture.class);
```

And now once your service is started then it won't stop unless you own or Android system kill it

Comment: I'm a real beginner.I will appreciate if someone say it crystal clear for me.

Comment: Well, what you want is not really beginner stuff... You could use a timer to startup your app / activity to do your thing.